# SwiftUI: Is there a difference between @StateObject initialization with closure or initializer?

Tags: swiftui, initialization, state

To clarify in code. Is there a difference between:

```
struct Shim: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = {
        let viewModel = ContentView.ViewModel()
        //do some configuration
        return viewModel
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        ContentView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}
```

AND

```
struct Shim: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ContentView.ViewModel
    
    init() {
        let viewModel = ContentView.ViewModel()
        //do some configuration
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ContentView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Option 1 would likely affect Concurrency. Add MainActor to the class to check.

Comment: It's a struct. Or do you mean ViewModel because that has @MainActor attached. But if you pick one over the other does that mean they are not the same?